# Is it possible to convert a time_t variable to struct tm without changing timezones?

Tags: c, time

I am given a time_t variable and I need to populate a struct tm with its value but I do not want GMT or UTC time, I do not want local time. I want the exact time value given from my time_t variable, I just want it to be formatted in the struct tm. After doing some digging it looks like this may not be possible but I wanted to ask here if anyone has a suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want UTC or your local time, do you know what time zone you *do* want?  `time_t` values are inherently UTC; they do not "know" what time zone they're for.  So to convert a `time_t` to a human-readable time, you always need to explicitly specify which time zone you want to display for.

Comment: If you truly want "the exact time value given from my `time_t` variable" then I'd say `gmtime` is what you do want.

Comment: So the program will save a file with a header that specifies its date, when the file is loaded in I would like a way to populate a label in the UI with its date but right now it is set up using struct tm so the it converts it to local time on the machine. I just need to display this time_t var which is some long long integer in the format of YYYY/MM/DD so it doesnt really matter what time zone it came from, I just need it to not be displayed differently when loaded to a machine with a different time zone.

Comment: Ahh okay I see what youre saying. I may need to find a way to get the timezone then from the "file save" side of things

Comment: If you are using `localtime()` to convert `time_t` to `struct tm`, you could do worse than just changing `localtime()` to `gmtime()`.  That would get you UTC, which you said you don't want, but it would at least get you something that is "not displayed differently when loaded on a machine with a different time zone".

Comment: @JesseWood: For "representation of time unaffected by local time zones" there's only really 3 standard options - UTC (standard fixed length seconds, with leap seconds), TAI  (standard fixed length seconds, without leap seconds), and Terrestrial Time (variable length seconds to match earth's rotation without leap seconds). Also note that sometimes what an OS calls UTC (and returns from `gmtime()`) is actually non-standard hacky rubbish that is not UTC (e.g. "UTC but with leap seconds replaced by stretching the length of a second over a 24 hour period").

Comment: @Brendan "Sometimes"? I don't know of an OS that *does* do UTC, with leap seconds, properly.  Do you?

Comment: @SteveSummit: Honestly, I don't know of an OS that does anything properly. Linux (since around 2015 I think) can be configured to try to support UTC (with leap seconds) properly (if enabled, if using NTP or PTP, if the wind is blowing in the right direction, ...) but there's no way for normal software to tell if Linux is broken (due to not doing leap seconds) or if Linux is broken (due to confusing unprepared user-space with leap seconds).

Comment: @JesseWood Please explain why "I do not want GMT or UTC time".